# Auto-save in VBA is reopening closed files

Tags: excel, vba

I implemented some code into a few of my excel sheets that would cause the file to autosave periodically. The issue I am running into with the code, is that when it is executed, it reopens the files that have been closed that also contain the same code.

I am looking for a way to have VBA autosave documents every so often, but it would no longer run if the file isn't open.

This is the code I have implemented:

Contained in "ThisWorkbook":

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("03:00:00"), "Save1"
End Sub
```

Contained in "Module 3":

```
Sub Save1()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("03:00:00"), "Save1"
End Sub
```

A note: The code between all of the documents is 100% identical (except the TimeValue, which varies by a few hours among some of them).

Comment: Why are you using VBA for this? Excel has it built-in.

Comment: The built in auto-save function will only save to One Drive, and will not save to the company's server. IT has advised they are unable to modify this (or just refuses to) so my only option was VBA.

Comment: You can use the Close event to cancel the OnTime

Answer (score 1):

Try the next approach, please:

1. Adapt the `OnTime` call to a better qualified `Sub`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 scheduleTime = Now + TimeValue("03:00:00")
 Application.OnTime scheduleTime, "Module3.Save1"
End Sub
```

2. Make the `Sub` in discussion `Private`, and create a new `Public` variable on top of the module:

```
Public scheduleTime As Date

Private Sub Save1()
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ThisWorkbook.Save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 
 scheduleTime = Now + TimeValue("03:00:00")
 Application.OnTime scheduleTime, "Module3.Save1"
End Sub
```

3. Clear the already set OnTime procedure:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Application.OnTime scheduleTime , "Module3.Save1", , False
End Sub
```

The first two items will solve the opening of other workbooks when the active workbook procedure is called. But, this should not happen and I am afraid that this is not the real opening mechanism, the workbooks are open by their own OnTime function call.

If my above supposition is `True`, **the item 3 alone** will solve the issue...

Comment: To cancel an `OnTime`, both the `Procedure` *and* the `EarliestTime` have to match: your code will only cancel you close the Workbook within a second of `Save1` running...

Comment: @Chronocidal: Yes, you are right. I must create a `Public` variable to keep la last scheduled time... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you may notice, `OnTime` is an `Application` method, **not** a `Workbook` method.

This means that, even if you close the Workbook, so long as the Excel Application is still open that `OnTime` is still counting down.  Once it hits zero, it will try to run the Subroutine - but the workbook is closed.  Rather than throw an Error, Excel will reopen the Workbook, and *then* run the Subroutine.

In order to stop this, you will need to unscheduled the Subroutine before you close the Workbook, which will also mean Storing the time.  So, you will need a Module that looks something like this:

```
Option Private Module
Option Explicit

Private AutoRunTime AS Date

Public Sub AutoSaveWorkbook()
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    AutoRunTime = Now()+TimeSerial(3,0,0) '3 hours
    Application.OnTime AutoRunTime, "AutoSaveWorkbook", True
End Sub

Public Sub CancelAutoSave()
    Application.OnTime AutoRunTime, "AutoSaveWorkbook", False
End Sub
```

Then, in the `Workbook_Open` even you call `AutoSaveWorkbook` to start things off, and in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` even you call `CancelAutoSave` to end them